# can not apply network map drive from "windows server 2008r2" on "windows 8" client

Tags: windows-8, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

We recently migrated our client machines to Windows 8 but the server still runs Windows 2008r2. When we are trying to apply create network drive from the server using GPO, it does not reflect on the Windows 8 client machines. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start:

Start with "Group Policy Management".

Go to the bottom: Group Policy Results.

Create a new "results" using the wizard using the machine and user in question.

Summary should show you an overview. Look especially to see if your GPO is in the "Alert" section. Details will give you more specific info as to whether that policy was applied or denied, and if denied why.

Would need more info to provide possibilities.